# WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation is always zero

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm working on a Xamarin Android app which runs for the most part in Portrait mode. However, now we are adding the functionality where if the user rotates the device they get another view in Landscape mode.

My issue is that when I try to use the following code snippet, rotation always has the value SurfaceRotation.Rotation0 (i.e. 0) no matter how I rotate the device.

```
var windowManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
var rotation = windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation; // Always gives zero
```

I am executing this code in a FragmentView (inherits from a base class, which inherits from MvxFragment). I have managed to get some code working using an OrientationEventListener, as follows, but this isn't ideal. I want to tap into the default Android behaviour for rotating a device, not define my own range of angles if possible:

```
// This works!
public override void OnOrientationChanged(int orientation)
    {
    if (app.IsPortrait && ((orientation >= 85 && orientation <= 95) || (orientation >= 265 && orientation <= 275)))
    {
        Mvx.Trace("Send message to open new view in landscape mode");           
    }
    else if (!app.IsPortrait && (orientation < 85 || (orientation > 95 && orientation < 265 ) || orientation > 275))
    {
        Mvx.Trace("Send message to close the landscape view");      
    }
}
```

I'm testing using a connected LGE Nexus 5 device and with a Samsung GT-19300 with the same results. Both devices have the Auto-rotate screen enabled. I do have a UI (as opposed to the issues [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626066/getrotation-always-returns-zero)). I've added

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to my manifest. Each view is set with the correct orientation when the Activity is declared (e.g. using ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait). Have I missed anything?

Thanks in advance!

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that when you specify an orientation for an activity by setting ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait (for example), the rotation (windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation) is always zero because the screen contents have not been rotated with respect to the device - regardless of the physical orientation of the device.

So, to solve my issue, I removed the ScreenOrientation setting for the Activity. This means that when the device is rotated the contents are also rotated (as per default Android behaviour) and when this happens the value of DefaultDisplay.Rotation is set as expected. This allows me to use the following code in my OrientationEventListener, OnOrientationChanged event:

```
if (app.IsPortrait && (rotation == ScreenOrientation.Landscape || rotation == ScreenOrientation.ReverseLandscape))
{
        Mvx.Trace("Send message to open new view in landscape mode");
}
else if (!app.IsPortrait && (rotation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait || rotation == ScreenOrientation.ReversePortrait))
{
        Mvx.Trace("Send message to close the landscape view"); 
}
```

David